# Why $O(|x|^{m+1})$ in Taylor expansion of $f \in C^m$ is incorrect?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

If this has been asked and answered before, I will delete the question.

Consider expanding $f(x+a)\in C^m$ for $m\in \mathbf{N}$ at $a=0$. Then writing $O(|x|^{x+1})$ in

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k + O(|x|^{m+1})$$

is not correct. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it might be $o(\vert x\vert^m)$ but not $O(\vert x\vert^{m+1})$. Take as an example $f(x)=\vert x\vert^\frac{3}{2}$ on the reals. It's continuously differentiable with $f'(x)=\frac32\operatorname{sgn}(x)\vert x\vert^\frac12$ ($\operatorname{sgn}$ being the signum function, returning $1$ for positive numbers, $-1$ for negative ones, and $0$ for $0$) and it's already in expanded form for $C^1$ functions, since $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, so $f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\vert x\vert^\frac32$. But clearly the remainder term $\vert x\vert^\frac32$ is not $O(\vert x\vert^2)$, just $o(\vert x\vert)$.

Comment: But $O(\vert x\vert^2) \implies o(|x|)$, no?

Comment: Yes, but the other direction doesn't hold.

Comment: Do you know how Taylor's formula reads with $o$ instead of $O$? The equation in my question would hold if $f\in C^{m+1}$, and I have seen this frequently, but not the formula using $o$.

Comment: Also, is not $f(x)=\vert x\vert^\frac{3}{2} \in C^{2}$ ?

Comment: Just replace $O(\vert x\vert^{m+1})$ by $o(\vert x\vert^m)$ and note that the formula holds for $f\in C^m$, not just $f\in C^{m+1}$.

Comment: And no, that function is not in $C^2$. Try calculating the second derivative and you will notice that at $x=0$ it doesn't exist.